# Getting multiple rows of the same thing from database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

I'm having some issues with this mysql database i got from school. I'm getting duplicate rows with the same name but different quantities. I would suppose that this is because 'inventory' contains columns with the same name as in 'sets'. But i really can't get it to work. Thank you in advance for all your help.

Database schematic (in Swedish, but the titles are in English.):
http://weber.itn.liu.se/~stegu76/TNMK30-2016/legodatabasen.pdf

[image: A screenshot from the results on the webpage]
**I'm very new to this so any tips would be appreciated.**

```
$setidquery = "SELECT inventory.Quantity, inventory.ItemID, inventory.ColorID, colors.Colorname, parts.Partname, sets.SetID, sets.Year, inventory.ItemtypeID FROM `inventory`, `parts`, `colors`, `sets` WHERE sets.SetID='$_COOKIE[setid]' AND inventory.ItemID=parts.PartID AND inventory.ColorID=colors.ColorID ORDER BY Partname ASC LIMIT 1000";

  echo "<table class=\"table\">";
  echo "<tr><th>Quantity:</th><th>Year:</th><th>Partname:</th><th>ItemID:</th><th>SetID</th><th>Image:</th></tr>";

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
      $prefix = "http://www.itn.liu.se/~stegu76/img.bricklink.com/";

      $Year = $row['Year'];
      $Quantity = $row['Quantity'];
      $ItemID = $row['ItemID'];
      $ColorID = $row['ColorID'];
      $Partname = $row['Partname'];
      $SetID = $row['SetID'];
      $ItemtypeID = $row['ItemtypeID'];

      $imagesearch = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE ItemTypeID = '$ItemtypeID' AND ItemID = '$ItemID' AND ColorID = '$ColorID' ");

      $imageinfo = mysqli_fetch_array($imagesearch);

      if($imageinfo['has_jpg']) {
        $filename = "$ItemtypeID/$ColorID/$ItemID.jpg";
      } else if($imageinfo['has_gif']) {
        $filename = "$ItemtypeID/$ColorID/$ItemID.gif";
      } else {
        $filename = "noimage_small.png";
      }

      echo "<tr>
              <td>$Year</td>
              <td>$Quantity</td>
              <td>$Partname</td>
              <td>$ItemID</td>
              <td>$SetID</td>
              <td><img src=\"$prefix$filename\" alt=\"Part $ItemID\"/></td>
            </tr>";
  }
      echo "</table>";
```

Here is the query formatted for readability:

```
SELECT inventory.Quantity, 
       inventory.ItemID, 
       inventory.ColorID, 
       colors.Colorname, 
       parts.Partname, 
       sets.SetID, sets.Year, 
       inventory.ItemtypeID
  FROM `inventory`, `parts`, `colors`, `sets`
 WHERE sets.SetID='$_COOKIE[setid]' 
  AND inventory.ItemID=parts.PartID
  AND inventory.ColorID=colors.ColorID
ORDER BY Partname ASC LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: That is because these `inventory`, `parts`, `colors`, `sets` tables contain the same information. It's a relational DB.

Comment: So tip 1: see about JOINs. We stopped writing queries this way ca. 1992!

Comment: How would that SQL statement look? Which ones should i join? All that have the same information i guess?

Comment: look up an explanation of the concept of, and the correct syntax for, writing queries using JOIN (either inner or outer as necessary depending on your data)

Comment: @PraveenP why would different tables with clearly different names contain the "same information"? What do you mean by this? Your comment doesn't make a lot of sense.

Comment: Yeah i tried to do this: 
$setidquery = "SELECT inventory.Quantity, inventory.SetID, inventory.ItemID, inventory.ColorID, parts.Partname, sets.SetID, sets.Year, inventory.ItemtypeID FROM `inventory`, `parts`, `colors`, `sets` INNER JOIN `inventory` ON inventory.SetID=sets.SetID WHERE sets.SetID='$_COOKIE[setid]' ORDER BY Partname ASC LIMIT 1000";

But it didnt work

Comment: @ADyson What I meant was, his original query fetch data from very specific fields that are also part of the other tables (foreign key). I.E `SetID` and `ItemtypeID`. Which, in my understanding, could case record duplication.

Comment: @FredrikBurmester https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Yeah i did read that. Tried some things but i couldn't get it to work

Comment: @PraveenP it's the style of join (or lack of explicit join) which is the issue, not which fields were selected. The query prefixes each field with the table name from which it should be selected, so that's not directly to blame (in fact the query would probably not execute if that wasn't done, because it wouldn't know which field to display).

Comment: @FredrikBurmester don't include inventory in your query _twice_ (as per the example in your comment above), unless that's really necessary, which it almost certainly isn't. The point is that each table should be JOINed to at least one other one, instead of just separating them with commas, and you need to explicitly specify INNER JOIN (or OUTER JOIN) and an ON clause for each join containing the fields on which to link the two tables.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you, i kind of get it. But the this that is messing with me is that i have so many tables, like i want to join inventory with sets because they both contain SetID which i think is the cause of the duplicate rows. But when there are so many tables i get confused.

Comment: @PraveenP  w3schools? Really? Friends don't let friends...

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that inventory, parts and colors are not joined to sets.

It is OK to do the joins in the where clause, but, as Strawberry says we prefer to write the joins in the from clause now.  I think that makes them easier to read, which helps to spot missing joins.

Here is your select statement (formatted to help me see what is going on):

```
select 
    inventory.quantity, 
    inventory.itemid,
    inventory.colorid,
    colors.colorname,
    parts.partname,
    sets.setid,
    sets.year,
    inventory.itemtypeid 
from
    inventory,
    parts,
    colors,
    sets 
where
    sets.setid='$_cookie[setid]' and 
    inventory.itemid = parts.partid and 
    inventory.colorid = colors.colorid 
order by 
    partname asc 
limit 1000;
```

And here is the join version.  I've shown the missing join with "?" where  you need to add something:

```
select 
    inventory.quantity, 
    inventory.itemid,
    inventory.colorid,
    colors.colorname,
    parts.partname,
    sets.setid,
    sets.year,
    inventory.itemtypeid 
from
    inventory
    join 
    parts
    on inventory.itemid = parts.partid
    join
    colors,
    on inventory.colorid = colors.colorid
    join
    sets 
    on set.? = ?.?
where
    sets.setid='$_cookie[setid]' 
order by 
    partname asc 
limit 1000;
```

The important thing is that there is no join to sets.  I would guess that there are three sets (for each of the examples shown anyway).  Because you have not said how to join to sets the query returns the other rows once for each set, in other words it joins to every set because you haven't restricted the join in any way.

If you want to learn more about SQL there are many options.  My website is  www.thedatastudio.net.

Comment: Exactly! When you do a `JOIN` with no `ON` condition, or a `FROM a,b` without a `WHERE a.something=b.something` SQL generates all possible combinations of rows from a and b. This shows up in your result set as a whole mess of duplicate rows that don't make much sense.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. (checked via school sql check website). But now i have an issue with my print. Nothing prints out. Everything is the same as in my OG post except that i removed the year.
i did this:
                    join
                    sets
                    on inventory.SetID = sets.SetID
 Thank you!